# How to set the "Google Earth Plugin" view as default in a Google Maps iframe?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am using this [Example](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/mapsapi/ggeoxml.html) and I want to set Google EARTH as default view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setMapType to set the desired mapType:

```
 map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP);
```

---

### `<edit>`:

The linked example uses the Maps-API V2, for V3 it's little bit different. Wait for the idle-event of the map and set the `mapType` to 'GoogleEarthAPI' .

Go to line 116 of your document and modify it:

```
if (isGEinstalled)
{
googleEarth = new GoogleEarth(map);
//add the following line
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'idle',function(){map.setMapTypeId('GoogleEarthAPI')});
}
else
{
  alert("O plugin de Google Earth nÃ£o estÃ¡ instalado");
}
```

Comment: Can you help me. I tried in this map and it didn't work, can you please tell me in wich line of the JS I should add it? http://j.mp/167CcJP it is is line 84 correct? But it dind't worked.

Comment: Amaizing! Simple and effective.